# How can I stop this scroll

Tags: jquery

var f1;
    var f2;
 var i=1;
    var again_again = 1;
    function again() {

go();
    }
    function go() {
      $('.floater').animate({
        left: "-=200px"}, 4000, 'linear', again);
    }

Answer (score 0):

```
var f1; 
var f2; 
var i=1; 
var again_again = 1; 

function again() { 
    //again_again = 1 - again_again; 
    //alert('sai'+ i); 
    i++; go(); 
} 

function init() { 
    f1 = $('#f1'); 
    f2 = $('#f2'); 
    go(); 
} 

function go() { 
    $('.floater').animate({ left: "-=200px"}, 4000, 'linear', again); 
}
```

use code sample for better view